# PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory Caused by ClassNotFound

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

i am using play jpa and encountered this.Searched complete Stackoverflow couldnt find the solution.

**What i am trying to is As localhost:9000 is hit , HomeController should add a table 'Product' in db "crud" which is already created in mysql.  So that would complete my 1st jpa program**

Here is my Persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">


<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <class>models.Product</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" 
value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crud"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" 
value="toor"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" 
value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Here is my application.conf

```
play.modules.enabled += "play.filters.csrf.CSRFModule"


play.filters.csrf {

  token {
    name = "csrfToken"
    sign = true
  }

  cookie {
    name = null
    secure = ${play.http.session.secure}
    httpOnly = false
  }

  body.bufferSize = ${play.http.parser.maxMemoryBuffer}
  bypassCorsTrustedOrigins = true

  header {
    name = "Csrf-Token"
    protectHeaders {
      Cookie = "*"
      Authorization = "*"
    }
    bypassHeaders {}
  }

  method {
    whiteList = ["GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"]
    blackList = []
  }

  contentType {
    whiteList = []
    blackList = []
  }

  errorHandler = null
}

play.crypto.secret="VRZV/ppo<t?;NKZN?
=PE<N;Yie_G^:sxQrL544YEl[fRsrE<:hMbT;Yj<WhG`bS@"


db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crud"
db.default.user=root
db.default.pass=toor
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
jpa.default = test
```

Here is the stacktrace

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:255)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:182)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$executeHandler$1$1.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:252)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$$nestedInanonfun$executeHandler$1$1.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:251)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$recoverWith$1(Future.scala:412)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transformWith$1(Promise.scala:37)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at play.api.libs.streams.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:68)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.dispatchOrAddCallback(Promise.scala:312)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: **Unable to build entity manager factory**
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at controllers.HomeController.index(HomeController.java:29)
    at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$2(Routes.scala:174)
    at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$3.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:136)
    at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$$anon$3.resultCall(HandlerInvoker.scala:135)
    at play.core.routing.HandlerInvokerFactory$JavaActionInvokerFactory$$anon$8$$anon$2$$anon$1.invocation(HandlerInvoker.scala:110)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:78)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [models.Product]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:245)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildHibernateConfiguration(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1136)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:853)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:54)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **Could not load requested class : models.Product**
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:230)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildHibernateConfiguration(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1136)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:853)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
```

Product.java (The model class)

```
package models;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Product {
    private static List<Product> products;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String ean;
    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String description;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(String ean, String name, String description) {
        this.ean = ean;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s -%s", this.ean, this.name);
    }

    static {
        products = new ArrayList<Product>();
        products.add(new Product("11111111", "Clip 1", "description 1"));
        products.add(new Product("22222222", "Clip 2", "description 2"));
        products.add(new Product("33333333", "Clip 3", "description 3"));
        products.add(new Product("44444444", "Clip 4", "description 4"));
        products.add(new Product("55555555", "Clip 5", "description 5"));
    }

    public static List<Product> findAll() {
        return new ArrayList<Product>(products);
    }

    public static Product findByEan(String ean) {
        for (Product candidate : products) {
            if (candidate.ean.equals(ean)) {
                return candidate;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static List<Product> findByName(String term) {
        final List<Product> results = new ArrayList<Product>();
        for (Product candidate : products) {
            if (candidate.name.toLowerCase().contains(term.toLowerCase())) {
                results.add(candidate);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    public static boolean remove(Product product) {
        return products.remove(product);
    }

    public void save() {
        products.remove(findByEan(this.ean));
        products.add(this);
    }

    public static List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public String getEan() {
        return ean;
    }

    public void setEan(String ean) {
        this.ean = ean;
    }

    public String   getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

And Homecontroller.java

```
package controllers;

import models.Product;
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
import play.data.FormFactory;
import play.libs.concurrent.HttpExecutionContext;
import play.mvc.*;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class HomeController extends Controller {

    private final FormFactory formFactory;
    private final HttpExecutionContext ec;

    @Inject
    public HomeController(FormFactory formFactory, HttpExecutionContext ec) {
        this.formFactory = formFactory;
        this.ec = ec;
    }

    public Result index() {
        //Create a database and add some entries
        Product newproduct=new Product();

        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory= Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
//Stuck at the above statment
        EntityManager entityManager=entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();


        newproduct.setEan("111");
        newproduct.setName("Lapy");
        newproduct.setDescription("Uska description");

        entityManager.persist(newproduct);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

        entityManager.close();
        entityManagerFactory.close();
        return ok(views.html.index.render("Database created check mysql"));
    }
}
```

EntitymanagerFactory is not able to load model class Product. I have tried various solution on this site otherwise i wouldnt post.

Comment: if it cant load a class then the class is not in a loadable location (i.e CLASSPATH). Since you don't provide info about WHAT is in the CLASSPATH then not sure what magical incantation people are supposed to offer ...

Comment: try to remove `static` from `private static List<Product> products;` in your `Product` class.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan didnt work

Comment: @NeilStockton in offical documentation a jpa example was given.They didnt use Entitymanagerfactory directly as i did. is that the problem ?

Comment: The problem is the class is not in the CLASSPATH. How you create an `EntityManagerFactory` has no bearing whatsoever on that! `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **Could not load requested class : models.Product**` means one thing, and one thing only

Comment: @NeilStockton How do i add that class in CLASSPATH in this scenario. i mean obviously play isnt doing it for me here . How do i do it manually ??

Comment: How can anyone answer that when you haven't said HOW you are defining the CLASSPATH and how your application is rung? Invoking via Maven? some other way? what IS in the CLASSPATH? some jars? any jars?

Comment: FYI i changed the model class and put it in controllers , Still the same error . controllers.Product instead of models.Product

Comment: i am using sbt . 1)sbt compile 2)sbt run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution finally , the code of creating entity manager factory and entity manager and beginning the transaction **should be written in the constructor** of the controller (i have written it in index method of Homecontroller). The database is created in mysql.

Comment: i actually don't know why this solved the problem, can anyone enlighten me ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below line from your persistence.xml

```
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
```

and just after the `<persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">` provide

```
<class>models.Product</class>
```

Comment: i had tried this by reading the other answers, Still not working

Answer (score 0):

Modify in the META-INF\persistence.xml the string : DefaultDS into DefaultDS